# Cannot change color of letter and border while hovering

Tags: html, css

When I am hovering over the blocks the color of the numbers are changing but not the literals which are accompany the blocks. I tried ways like "key-selector:hover {color:white}" but it is not working. What can I do to solve my problem and what is the reason for that the common way is not working. Thank you.

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  /*background-color: rgb(116, 181, 218);*/
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  opacity: 0.65;
  color: white;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #333;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">Mandant</a></li>
  <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html">Anliegen</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="options">
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>A</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>D</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>E</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="button-bar">
  <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
    < Zurück</div>
      <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Weiter ></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example. i have added a couple of lines to your code (lines 96 - 98). I think you get the idea and can change it so it fits what you want to du

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 4rem;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  /*background-color: rgb(116, 181, 218);*/
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  opacity: 0.65;
  color: white;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}

.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #333;
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: white;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="client.html">Mandant</a></li>
  <li class="section"><a class="nav-text" href="case.html">Anliegen</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="options">
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>A</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">1</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">2</div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">3</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>D</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">4</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="key-selector">
        <span>E</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="button-bar">
  <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
    < Zurück</div>
      <div class="nav-inner" id="forward"> Weiter ></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!. Can you explain me this kind of syntax in line 96, I am not familiar with this.

Comment: on css you can have selectors like this `.parent-class .child-class`. this would apply your style the elements with the `child-class` only if they are children of an element with the `parent-class`. When you say `button:hover .my-class` you say that you want to apply your styles to an element with the class `my-class` only if it is a child of a button if is being hovered.
Take a look here, lots of good info about css selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try using pseudo class for button followed by `.key-selector`:

```
.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: white;
}
```

Here is a snipped, is it what you meant?

```css
.navbar {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
gap: 4rem;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 45px;
left: 0;
top: 0;


}

.nav-text {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  position:sticky;
 left: 8rem;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16.8px;

  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;

}

.text {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.button:hover {
  /*background-color: rgb(116, 181, 218);*/
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  opacity: 0.65;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover .key-selector {
  color: white;
}

#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
  color: white;
}


.key-selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;


  opacity: 0.6;
 
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;

  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #333;
}
  

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;

}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 83px;
    
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<ul class = "navbar">
        <li class = "section"><a class = "nav-text" href = "client.html">Mandant</a></li>
        <li class = "section"><a class = "nav-text" href = "case.html">Anliegen</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class = "options">
      <div class = "option">
        <div class="button">
          <div class="key-selector">
            <span>A</span>
          </div>
          <div class="text">1</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <div class="button">
          <div class = "key-selector">
            <span >B</span>
          </div>
          <div class="text">2</div>
        </div>
       

      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <div class="button">
          <div class = "key-selector">
            <span>C</span>
          </div>
          <div class="text">3</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <div class="button">
          <div class = "key-selector">
          <span >D</span>
        </div>
          <div class="text">4</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <div class="button">
          <div class = "key-selector">
            <span >E</span>
          </div>
          <div class="text">5</div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </div>
    
        
        <div class = "button-bar">
            <div class = "nav-inner" id = "backward"> <  Zurück</div>
            <div class = "nav-inner" id = "forward">  Weiter  ></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```